# Geometry Collection Support for DB2

Tags: geometrycollection, db2

At first glance it looked like DB2 supported Geometry Collections but this doesn't appear to be the case. I've tried adding a WKT like:

```
GEOMETRYCOLLECTION (POINT (40 10),
LINESTRING (10 10, 20 20, 10 40),
POLYGON ((40 40, 20 45, 45 30, 40 40)))
```

But I get

`Unknown type "GEOMETRYCOLLECTION" in WKT`

It appears that DB2 sees a Geometry Collection as some kind of base-type for the Multi-Part geometries, which is at odds with all the other providers. Can anyone confirm this or am I missing something here in the way they are representing it? It's kinda odd.

Comment: By reading https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/9.7?topic=parameters-st-geomcollfromtxt I guess that you are right.

Comment: Yeah, kinda sucks. The first line "ST_GeomCollFromTxt takes a well-known text representation of a geometry collection" isn't true unless they are determining how one defines a WKT representation of a geometry collection. Disappointing.